# Insert data into just one column from csv

Tags: sql-server, csv, sql-insert

Somehow, one of the columns in one of my tables in my database now shows all `NULL` values throughout all 1000 rows. If I have a CSV file of the data is it possible to insert the data of just that one column into the database without disturbing the existing information without large amounts of queries?

Comment: You can use [`Openrowset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql) to open a csv file like a table/view, then you must have an index that is same in both, So just `update` your table set your column of your table with data from `Openrowset` result based on that index - HTH ;).

Comment: As long as the CSV file has the information needed to join it's data to the existing data (preferably the primary key). Since this sounds like this is a "one time fix" and there's only 1K rows, the easiest solution may be to open the file in Excel and then an Excel formula to script out the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was me I'd probably just upload (use the Import/Export wizard) your csv to a new table then just join between the old table and the new (import) table and run an update - very simple.